# How to find the cell where a substring is located within an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to write a function that searches through a list of song lyrics and identifies the song title and artist. This is what the table looks like:

Edit: Figure 1 - "Worksheet 1"
[image]

Using a search field, it's currently able to determine whether or not the query is present throughout the given lyrics. This is what it looks like as well as the function I used to prove if it's there or not:

Edit: Figure 2 - "Worksheet 2"
[image]

("Lyrics" is the array range with all of the lyrics.)

Now, I essentially need to grab the cell(s) in which the query is present. I want it to grab the "Song ID #" associated with the lyric.

Edit: Although the data is all in worksheet 1, the function is going to be in E4 of worksheet 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B5,D:D,))
```

.

**UPDATE**

It turns out that the text is thousands of characters long in most cells.

MATCH fails if it has not made the match by the time it hits a element that has more than 255 characters.

An alternative formula which works is this:

```
=INDEX(SongID,MATCH(1,--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B4,Lyrics)),))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I think it has something to do with the fact that "MATCH" only returns exact cell matches. As you can see from my first figure, it contains the entire song lyric. I need the function to be able to search for the individual query within the huge array!

Comment: Umm. It does work. Tested before posted and tested again now. It works with the exact data from your question.

Comment: Maybe is has something to do with how long the lyrics are? If I type in a bunch of random words (one of which being the query), it locates it properly! However, with the lyrics I've pasted in, it returns N/A. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've updated my answer here and sent the workbook back to you via email.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*"&B5&"*",D:D,0))
```

Note that if the search term appears in more than one song only the first `Song ID` of a match will be returned.

[image: SO33483743 example]

Having at last divulged the sheet name:

```
=INDEX('worksheet 1'!A:A,MATCH("*"&B5&"*",'worksheet 1'!D:D,0))
```

Comment: Returns #N/A. I think it's because =MATCH searches the complete cell and not all the substrings.

Comment: The 2nd sheet with the black background. It's going into E4.

Comment: @ZacharyRosenberg I've tested this and confirm it works. With the "*"'s at the beginning and end of the search term, MATCH looks for all substrings within each cell of an array.

Comment: @pnuts your image is not doing what I'm trying to find! You took the B5 part from the other worksheet. I need to search through the song lyrics (D:D) and see if it can find the desired search.

Comment: @pnuts okay. I made edits explaining which is from what workbook. And at the end, I state what the real goal is. Thanks

Comment: @ZacharyRosenberg if you can't figure out how to change a formula from referencing one sheet to another, you should figure that out before you finish this homework.

Comment: JESUS CHRIST! Both you and @pnuts assume I'm stupid or something.... I know more than well how to cross-reference one formula to another sheet! That is straight up not the issue here. I was simply asking this forum for help, not non-constructive criticism. There is evidently a problem with the function not being able to recognize the query within the massive song lyric. The functions you provided are correct to an extent, but they are still not working with my given scenario. I am more than happy to send you the file if you'd like to see for yourself.

Comment: If it helps, I would not have arrived at that conclusion without your original help. However, your negative feedback was not necessary. Now that you understand the issue, do you have a true answer?